# Which algorithm/loss function for better precision on a balanced binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I have a huge tabular dataset consisting of millions of samples for a binary classification problem. The set is very balanced almost 1:1.

The data is however very noisy and I only care about precision and not accuracy. 
What is needed is that when one model predicts 1 it's actually a 1 (same for 0), in other words the true positive rate and true negative rate.

Therefore , it's fine if the model can only predict accurately a few of the samples but the predictions must be accurate.

XGBoost using a threshold probabilityis giving me the best result but it's still not good enough. Can you suggest something better, like a better algorithm or a loss/metric function to use

Comment: Its hard to be too precise since we don't know your context, but if I'm understanding this correctly, your algorithm will output `0`, `1`, or `?` and all you care about is the accuracy when it outputs `0` or `1`. Is that the correct understanding? If so, one question is: in what way is your algorithm not doing well? Is it answers `?` too much or is it wrong when it answers `0` and `1`?

Comment: Are you only using a single probability cutoff? If you mostly care about high true-positive and true-negative rates for a small fraction of your cases and don't care about most cases, then consider using cases above a very high probability cutoff for positives and cases below a very low probability cutoff for negatives. Also, be careful with use of the word "accuracy" as its accepted meaning in this context is (true calls)/(total population). See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_(classification_context)).

Comment: @roundsquare It outputs a probability for 1 or 0.  My problem is it's not learning well enough, probably because it is trying to find a good fit for the whole training dataset while I only care that when it says 1 or 0, it's an actual 1 or 0. 

In other words if it's says 1 with 0.5 probability, I don't care but if it says 1 with high probability it's really important it's a 1. Same for 0

Comment: @EdM Thank you for your anwser. I am currently using a probability for a cuttoff but since the data is very noisy (many cases can't be predicted using the features) only a few testing samples are predicted with high probability than 0.55 and all are under 0.6.